# Named async function causing "task.apply is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am trying to write an async waterfall using **async/await** functions.

This works:

```js
async.waterfall([
  async function() {
    let test = await foo();
      return test;
    }
],
function(err, results) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(results);
});
```

However, when I define the function below and then call it by its name in the array, like so:

```
async function myFunction() {
  let test = await foo();
  return test;
}

async.waterfall([
  myFunction() 
],
function(err, results) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(results);
});
```

I receive the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: task.apply is not a function

I am trying to get my named async function to work within the waterfall.

Comment: In your first example, you're passing a function reference that the async library can call later.  In your second example, you're calling the function immediately and passing the promise that it returns.  These are completely different in how they execute.  Remove he parens after `myFunction` and then you'd be passing a function reference in the second example too.

Comment: Also, is the async library promise aware?  Will it wait for the promise that `myFunction()` returns?

Comment: You should not use the async.js library with `async function`s and `await` syntax when you already have promises available. You don't need that library. Do not mix promises with callback style.

Comment: @Bergi, noted. I will look into restructuring my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `myFunction` should be passed as reference and not be called directly, e.g.:

```js
async function myFunction() {
    let test = await foo();
    return test;
}


async.waterfall([
    myFunction
],
function(err, results) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```

does that help?